# Why is PySpark not reading data from kafka using streaming, but works fine with reading it normally?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to read in data from kafka using structured streaming, but the program doesn't seem to be getting any of it.

This code doesn't print any records to the console:

```
KAFKA_TOPIC = "stations-topic"
KAFKA_SERVER = "kafka:9092"

sc = SparkContext("local[4]")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("stations").getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_SERVER) \
    .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC) \
    .load()

df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

df2 = df1.select(from_csv(col("value"), df_schema_string).alias("stations"))

df3 = df2.select("stations.*")

out = df3 \
    .writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .start()

out.awaitTermination()
```

But if I modify it to not use streaming like this:

```
KAFKA_TOPIC = "stations-topic"
KAFKA_SERVER = "kafka:9092"

sc = SparkContext("local[4]")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("stations").getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

df = spark \
    .read \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_SERVER) \
    .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC) \
    .load()

df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

df2 = df1.select(from_csv(col("value"), df_schema_string).alias("stations"))

df3 = df2.select("stations.*")

df3.show(10)
```

it prints the top 10 rows of data without issues. Any clue on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, I had to add `.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")` to the readStream